# What is the equivalent of regexp \Q...\E in postgresql?

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
   field
FROM
   myTable
WHERE
   field ~ '\\Qprefix[\\E.+'
```

It won't find values like `prefix[foo]`.

How can I replace `\Q..\E` ?

Comment: What exactly does `\Q` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name _"Many flavors also support the `\Q…\E` escape sequence. All the characters between the `\Q` and the `\E` are interpreted as literal characters."_ http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: you can use "Regular Expression Metasyntax". Normally the flavor of RE being used is determined by regex_flavor. However, this can be overridden by a director prefix. If an RE begins with ***:, the rest of the RE is taken as an ARE regardless of regex_flavor. If an RE begins with ***=, the rest of the RE is taken to be a literal string, with all characters considered ordinary characters. Refer to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Perl's `\Q .. \E` syntax is equivalent to find `([^\w])`, replace with `\\$1`. Maybe you could do it by hand if constants. If variables, maybe you could do a separate regex on the variable if your language supports it.

Comment: For example, `prefix\[.+`

Comment: @DanilaLadner Can you provide a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form of regex with a `\Q..\E` unquoted substring is only supported by [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/), which is not available natively in PostgreSQL.

If your program must deal with this syntax in general, the PCRE support can be installed as an extension, as provided here: https://github.com/petere/pgpcre

On the other hand, if it's only that one regex that should be made to work, first
note that the double backslashes in `'\\Qprefix[\\E.+'` means literally two backslashes with PostgreSQL 9.1 and above, unless `standard_conforming_strings` is explicitly switched to `OFF`.
To be insensitive to this setting, literals with the old syntax are expected to be prefixed with `E`. This is described in [String Constants with C-style Escapes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE) in the doc.

To simply match `prefix[foo]` with a PostgreSQL-style regex with the modern syntax, this works:

```
test=> show standard_conforming_strings ;
 standard_conforming_strings 
-----------------------------
 on
(1 row)

test=> select 'prefix[foo]' ~ 'prefix\[.+';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```